# Regular expressions to find user name

Tags: regex, perl

so I have for example:

```
Mar 22 09:05:06 test sshd[8156]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=111.111.111.111  user=root
Mar 15 06:35:01 test CRON[22947]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user bogdan
```

And I have to find user name using regular expressions. I know, that to word "user " and "user=" I can use this:

```
while($linelist = <>)
{
 if($linelist =~ /(\buser[ =]{1})/)
 {
    print $1;
 }
}
```

But how can I find for example "bogdan" or "root"? And other users's names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{1}` is redundant.

```
if (my ($user) = $linelist =~ /\buser[ =](.*)/) {
    print "$user\n";
}
```

Enclosing $user in parentheses creates list context for the binding operator, so $1 is returned. If there could be some information after the username, you'd have to restrict the * (e.g. `/\buser[ =]([^ ]*)/`).